# Want to call Javabean method in HTML onclick (jsp)

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, servlets

For a school assignment I have to make a connection to a database from a JSP page using a Java bean, which works so far. 
Everytime I press this button I want to call a method in my bean..

```
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="To DB!"  OnClick="<% DBbean.InsertStatement(); %>" style="width:100%; height:50px ">
```

Only this doesn't work.. does anyone have an idea how i can solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some advice:

1. Don't continue down this path.  Learn and follow the Sun Java coding standards.  You're using C# style; it'd be confusing to another Java developer.
2. Don't continue down this path.  Your app should use CSS, not mingle style in with markup.
3. Don't continue down this path.  Your app should not be doing such back end things in the view layer.
4. Don't continue down this path.  Your app will be susceptible to SQL injection, because you aren't binding or validating input from users.
5. Don't continue down this path.  You should not write JSPs with scriptlet code in them; learn JSTL.

If you must, use JSTL `<sql>` tags or `#include` the bean of your choice and call its methods.  But I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the difference between client-side and server-side code. When you click a button on a web-page, that triggers something happening ON THE CLIENT. When you make a request (enter a URL in the address-bar on the browser, click a link, post a form) that will trigger something happening ON THE SERVER. The two are completely separated.

To achieve what you are proposing, you will need to have a form on your page (`<form>`) that posts to a servlet on your server. In that servlet, you connect to the database and do whatever before returning a new page to the browser.

EDIT: as this seem to be pretty much the gist of the current course element you are taking, you should ask your teacher/tutor for some guidance if you are stuck on this.